# Get the sorted indices of an array using quicksort

Tags: c, quicksort

I have changed to quicksort code to sort an array of floats which I got from **tutorialgatway.org**. However I need the sorted indices. I am aware of the `qsort` library function that can be used to get the sorted indices and I can implement that. However, I want to avoid standard library (I know this is not recommendation). The reason for not using a standard library is that I need to sort large number of arrays in a loop, which I need to parallelize using `openMP`, therefore writing function explicitly would allow me to parallelize quicksort function in a loop.

```
/* C Program for Quick Sort */
#include <stdio.h>

void Swap(float *x, float *y) {
    float Temp;
    Temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = Temp;
}

void quickSort(float a[], int first, int last) {
    int i, j;
    int pivot;
    if (first < last) {
        pivot = first;
        i = first;
        j = last;
        while (i < j) {
            while (a[i] <= a[pivot] && i < last)
                i++;
            while (a[j] > a[pivot])
                j--;
            if (i < j) {
                Swap(&a[i], &a[j]);
            }
        }
        Swap(&a[pivot], &a[j]);
        quickSort(a, first, j - 1);
        quickSort(a, j + 1, last);
    }
}

int main() {
    int number, i;
    float a[100];
    printf("\n Please Enter the total Number of Elements  :  ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("\n Please Enter the Array Elements  :  ");
    for (i = 0; i < number; i++)
        scanf("%f", &a[i]);

    quickSort(a, 0, number - 1);
    printf("\n Selection Sort Result : ");
    for (i = 0; i < number; i++)  {
        printf(" %f \t", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

How can I return the sorted indices in the code ?

Comment: Note that `qsort()` may not be implementing a quicksort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate an array of indexes from 0 to size-1, then sort the array of indexes according to the array values. So the code does compares using array[index[...]], and does swaps on index[...].

An alternative is to generate an array of pointers from &array[0] to &array[size-1]. When the pointers are sorted, you can convert them to indexes by using: index[i] = pointer[i] - &array[0] (could use a union for the indexes and pointers).

---

Example program with standard version of Hoare partition scheme to sort array of indexes in I[] according to floats in A[]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void QuickSort(float A[], size_t I[], size_t lo, size_t hi)
{
    if (lo < hi)
    {
        float pivot = A[I[lo + (hi - lo) / 2]];
        size_t t;
        size_t i = lo - 1;
        size_t j = hi + 1;
        while (1)
        {
            while (A[I[++i]] < pivot);
            while (A[I[--j]] > pivot);
            if (i >= j)
                break;
            t = I[i];
            I[i] = I[j];
            I[j] = t;
        }
        QuickSort(A, I, lo, j);
        QuickSort(A, I, j + 1, hi);
    }
}

#define COUNT (4*1024*1024)             // number of values to sort

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    int  r;                             // random number
    size_t i;

    float  * A = (float *)  malloc(COUNT*sizeof(float));
    size_t * I = (size_t *) malloc(COUNT*sizeof(size_t));

    for(i = 0; i < COUNT; i++){         // random floats
        r  = (((rand()>>4) & 0xff)<< 0);
        r += (((rand()>>4) & 0xff)<< 8);
        r += (((rand()>>4) & 0xff)<<16);
        r += (((rand()>>4) & 0xff)<<24);
        A[i] = (float)r;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)          // array of indexes
        I[i] = i;

    QuickSort(A, I, 0, COUNT-1);

    for(i = 1; i < COUNT; i++){
        if(A[I[i-1]] > A[I[i]]){
            printf("error\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    free(I);
    free(A);

    return(0);
}
```

---

This version of quicksort avoids stack overflow by only using recursion of the smaller side of the partition. Worst case time complexity will still be O(n^2), but the stack space complexity is limited to O(log(n)).

```
void QuickSort(float A[], size_t I[], size_t lo, size_t hi)
{
    while (lo < hi)
    {
        float pivot = A[I[lo + (hi - lo) / 2]];
        size_t t;
        size_t i = lo - 1;
        size_t j = hi + 1;
        while (1)
        {
            while (A[I[++i]] < pivot);
            while (A[I[--j]] > pivot);
            if (i >= j)
                break;
            t = I[i];
            I[i] = I[j];
            I[j] = t;
        }
        /* avoid stack overflow */
        if((j - lo) < (hi - j)){
            QuickSort(A, I, lo, j);
            lo = j+1;
        } else {
            QuickSort(A, I, j + 1, hi);
            hi = j;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am bit confused about creating array of index. If I do that, I would need to write another swap function that can take integers as an arguments? In that case, do I just repeat last 3 lines in quickSort function for index array ? And similar thing for if  loop which has also has Swap there?

Comment: @dipaksanap - I just notice a problem, you want pivot to be a value, not an index, in this case `float pivot = a[first+(last-first)/2]; `. The middle value eliminates the need to check for `i < last` .  You would compare (array[index[...]], pivot), but swap (index[...], index[...]).

Comment: When I change the pivot to a[first+(last-first)/2] program runs forever. I think the program is written with 1st element of an array to be the pivot.

Comment: @dipaksanap - that should be `pivot = a[index[first+(last-first)/2]];`, as the code is sorting indexes. I updated my answer with example code with slight changes in the quick sort partition logic.

Comment: Nice clean implementation. Too bad it explodes when all array elements have identical values.

Comment: @rcgldr: indeed you are correct, the uniform value array is not a pathological case, but one can be constructed with `antiqsort`... Recursing on the smaller half and iterating on the larger one avoids the stack overflow, but does not reduce the quadratic complexity on these pathological cases.

Comment: @chqrlie - I updated my answer to show a version that avoids stack overflow. I could also add median of 3, but I think the main point was to modify the OP's code to sort an array of indexes according to the array of data, and since the middle value is being used for pivot, already sorted or reverse sorted data is not a worst case issue.

Comment: @rcgldr: that's better... No more crashes on bad distribution, just slowliness. Leave median of 3 out of the picture, it does not completely prevent the pathological cases anyway. Too bad I cannot upvote twice :(

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks a lot for help!!! I can implement it now, may be latter even the Quicksort itself can be parallelized, hope to get there soon. Thanks everyone again for your helpful comments.